# Nginx Php5.6 unusually long TTFB > 2 mins

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fastcgi

I have setup Nginx and PHP-FPM app with Symfony 2 inside a docker container. CUrrently it does not point to the DB or elasticsearch and only serve static content. Unfortunately it takes more than 100 seconds to load the landing page and I cannot figure out why.
I have set `fastcgi_timeout 300; (nginx.conf)`and `php_max_execution_time = 300` (php.ini). 
[image: Below is my network timing diagram from Chrome]

Comment: You're going to have to attach a debugger.

Comment: Try a plain HTML file or text, not served through Symfony, does it also take 2min? Is the 2min value consistent, I mean exactly 120s every time?  If yes, sounds like some kind of timeout or limit somewhere.